# SQL Query to average multiple data and compare with one data point to check offset

Tags: sql, postgresql, grafana

I am new to SQL so please bear with me. In one of my tables I have a series of inverter voltage values, written every minute. I am displaying the data on GRAFANA and would like to find anomalous points, if any. A really simple solution for me now is to get the average of all voltages at a specific time, and see whether 1 value is off by "a lot".

Some background: Using postresql, and the columns "timestamp", "value", "name"
name is the identifier and right now the inverters are in the format 'INVX_INVERTER_SG_Branch VoltageY' where Y = {1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23} and X = {01-18}.

The first temporary query works as expected, it produces a table of timestamps and average values of all combinations at that time. In the second SELECT query I am getting bullshit values. There is no other data with name containing 'SG_Branch Voltage' on the DB Table. Our friendly chatgpt is spitting garbage.

Ideally the result will show me timestamps and values for anomalous points. I shall then plot those points on the graph. This will simply be an indicator of the point being not as expected.

```
WITH average AS (
    SELECT
        "timestamp",
        AVG(value) AS avg_value
    FROM
        st_values
    WHERE
        "timestamp" BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '1 day' AND NOW() AND
        "name" LIKE 'INV%_INVERTER_SG_Branch Voltage%'
    GROUP BY "timestamp"
)
SELECT
    v."timestamp",
    v.value
FROM
    st_values v
JOIN
    average av ON av."timestamp" = v."timestamp"
WHERE
    v."timestamp" BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '1 day' AND NOW() AND
    v."name" LIKE 'INV%_INVERTER_SG_Branch Voltage%' AND
    ABS(v.value - av.avg_value) / av.avg_value > 0.3 
ORDER BY
    v."timestamp";
```

The code above is (semi?) not working. I am not sure how to debug this. This yields points that are truly anomalous (i.e. lie on one of my lines) but some that are (fake?) not lying on any lines.

Edit : A screenshot of the results. As you can see some red dots are on the purple (anomalous) line, however some are above the line where no values should be

[image: Sample data]

Comment: *"not sure how to debug this"*: add to the outer select columns v.name and av.avg_value and investigate from there. Also, are you sure timestamps of measurements for all inverters are the same?

Comment: Your SQL structure is correct, but the reason for the extra points may be that you are using the mean instead of the median. Because you are looking for outliers, and the mean itself is sensitive to outliers.

To use the median, replace AVG(value) with PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY value).

Comment: @AntonIvanov You are absolutely right, however my issue is not that I pick up non-outliers as outliers, it is that new data is being shown. Refer to the edit above

Comment: @markalex I tried this and the names are correct, what I would expect, so is the average value. Inverter values though are incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in your query that could spawn bogus values. It might be worth it to revisit your `WHERE` conditions:

1. If you only want these sources:

   ```
   X = {01-18} and Y = {1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23}.
   ```

   You can express specifically that, instead of resorting to the catch-all `%` in the regular expression:

   ```sql
   "name" SIMILAR TO 
   'INV(0[1-9]|1[0-8])\_INVERTER\_SG\_Branch Voltage(1|3|5|7|9|11|13|15|17|19|21|23)' 
   ESCAPE '\'

   "name" ~ 
   'INV(0[1-9]|1[0-8])_INVERTER_SG_Branch Voltage(1|3|5|7|9|11|13|15|17|19|21|23)'
   ```

   Which works just as well for both SQL standard regular expression ([`SIMILAR TO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP)) and POSIX syntax ([`~`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)), except the escaping part: `_` underscore is a single-character wildcard in `LIKE` and `SIMILAR TO`. `\` backslash is their default escape character, so the `ESCAPE '\'` is just for verbosity.

   I wouldn't suspect you overlooked a variant of the text that your wildcard caught against your intention, but this could technically be the case.
2. You could also make sure the unexpected values you're getting aren't there because you're feeding the data into the table having a different [`TimeZone`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES) setting than when you reading it here. In such case this

   ```sql
   "timestamp" BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '1 day' AND NOW()`
   ```

   could be getting you *less* than the last 24h of data, if the source is behind, or a 24h slice between 4h and 28h ago, if the source is 4h ahead. If your `"timestamp"` column is actually `timestamptz`, this shouldn't be a problem.
3. You didn't share what "the lines" are and how exactly you plot them, but that could also be the source of error.

Unfortunately, without a reproducible example that's mostly just guesswork.

---

[Window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) can get you the same result, significantly faster and with less code: [DB<>Fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/9QkkpbzH)

```sql
SELECT "timestamp", value FROM (
    SELECT "timestamp",
           value,
           ABS(value - avg(value)over w1) / avg(value)over w1 as deviation
    FROM st_values
    WHERE "timestamp" BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '1 day' AND NOW()
      AND "name" LIKE 'INV%_INVERTER_SG_Branch Voltage%'
    WINDOW w1 AS (PARTITION BY "timestamp") ) AS subq
WHERE .3 < deviation
ORDER BY "timestamp"
```

Since you're dealing with time series data, you can remove the [default 10% empty space](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html#INDEX-RELOPTION-FILLFACTOR) in your index to speed things up. You can also squeeze everything of interest into the index and get [index-only scans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html):

```sql
create index tnv_idx on st_values ("timestamp","name")
  include("value")
  with(fillfactor=100);
```

If you have queries that still need to run sequential scans, those could benefit from a [`cluster`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-cluster.html):

```sql
cluster st_values using tnv_idx;
```

Comment: Hello Zegarek, thanks for you answer. I have changed the query based on your first point to make sure I dont pick up other data by accident. 

For 2., indeed the timestamp are timestampz

For 3. I edited my question to include a screenshot

Comment: @Kryrena Thanks for addressing each point. Did you try to maybe run the last query from [the demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/jb3hIyL_) to see exactly what sources the regular expression pattern picks up? The screenshot you attached shows graphs for DC voltages 1-23 for only inverter `01`, while both your pattern and mine collect values for those voltages from 17 more inverters. Is it possible the red dots simply originate from any of the 204 other sources?

Comment: @Kryrena I also realised `_` is a single-character wildcard in `SIMILAR TO` and `LIKE`, so unless you switch to POSIX regex `~`, the underscores need to be escaped. I added that to the answer and [the demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/9QkkpbzH) near the end.

Comment: funny enough it works without it being escaped. I found the issue, however your window function query seems to be much faster so Ill go with that one!

Comment: The issue lies in the `WHERE`
clauses, with the `INV%` being the culprit. The way the query is written makes it so a mean of all Inverter sub Voltages is taken, which works when the values of ALL inverters are shown. In my graph I only saw the values for 1 inverter. Without your idea of posting a screenshot I would have never thought that I was looking at a subset of the data with anomalies calculate for the whole set. Was about to post this answer but since you are the one who found it go ahead :)

Comment: @Kryrena The pattern without escaped `_` does work but the thing is it works *too well* - demo shows how it could catch names with anything else in place of any of those. It's good to narrow it down, but it won't matter until you actually get some rows with names like that, otherwise there's nothing more to catch. Congrats on finding and fixing the thing - I think me being the second pair of eyes didn't hurt, but ultimately I kind of expected one pair of eyes just taking a second look will be enough. It's always funny how solutions come immediately *after* showing someone the problem.